# No sending SMS with KDE Connect for a Blackberry Key 2 phone

Tags: kde, sms, blackberry

I'm new to Ubuntu and have installed KDE Connect SMS to be able to do the same thing I was doing with Microsoft's Mobile Connect for Windows. I can read my SMS, but the "New" button isn't accessible, so it's not much use. Is there a solution other than KDE Connect? My phone is a Blackberry Key 2.

Comment: Have you enabled send SMS on the KDE connect app on the phone and on KDE connect on the computer? Moreover, I want to do the same a with Microsoft Mobile Connect is not very descriptive. I assume you want to send SMS.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Edit and set the title to be english; "No sending SMS with KDE Connect for a Blackberry Key 2"  <- google translate.

Comment: Also, which version of Ubuntu/Kubuntu are you using? KDE connect has evolved a lot in the recent years, and a recent version of KDE connect (bundled with a recent version of Ubunttu, like 23.10) will have more features.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my poor English ! I am using Ubuntu 22.04 3 LTS. Sending SMS is enabled both on my phone and my computer. I can read the SMS with KDE Connect but the button "New" is grey...